# Nginx rewrite in subfolder (404)

Tags: wordpress, nginx, http-status-code-404

I has a site host on a **NGINX** server which used to work fine to remove `index.php` in nginx site config using `try_files`.

But now I am going to add a blog on it, where the URL will be `www.foo.com/blog`, I can access the blog and use `index.php?p=`.

But, once I use *pretty* permalink with Nginx Helper, `www.foo.com/blog/2013/07/bar`, I get `404`.

```
server {
  # don't forget to tell on which port this server listens
  listen 80;

  # listen on the www host
  server_name foo.com;

  # and redirect to the non-www host (declared below)
  return 301 $scheme://www.ultra-case.com$request_uri;
}

server {
  # listen 80 default_server deferred; # for Linux
  # listen 80 default_server accept_filter=httpready; # for FreeBSD
  listen 80;

  # The host name to respond to
  server_name www.foo.com;

  # Path for static files
  root /web/foo.com

  #index file
  index index.php;

  #Specify a charset
  charset utf-8;

  # Custom 404 page
  error_page 404 /404.html;

  # Uri Rewrite

  location /blog {
    index index.php;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /blog/index.php?$args;
  }

  location / {
    autoindex on;
    # This is cool because no php is touched for static content.
    # include tihe "?$args" part so non-default permalinks doesn't break when using query string
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
  }
  location ~ \.php$ {
    #NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini
    include fastcgi.conf;
    fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
  }

  # Include the component config parts for h5bp
  include conf/h5bp.conf;
}
```

Comment: `root /web/foo.com` semi colon missing

Comment: @MohammadAbuShady um... sorry for my fault, it is just mistake while I want to hidden my real server hostname and location of files.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The accepted answer routes everything through `index.php`. 
This will break certain script includes, the *wp-admin* script being one of them.

#### You can use:

```
location /blog/ {
    index index.php;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /blog/index.php?$args;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've tried every other solutions and this one helped me.

Comment: I burned 5 hours trying to figure this out. Thank you, thank you, thank you.

Comment: Thanks a million! This is just what I needed.

Comment: That's save me my headache!! Thanks Million and Up Vote!

Comment: Saved my day! Thanks

Comment: Worked with me after removing the last slash in the path, **/blog/** to **/blog**
might help some one.
Thank you!!

Comment: Your answer deserved the best answer of the year, thank you

Answer (score 17):

Um... Thank you for all comments and answer. But finally I use this method to get it works

```
location /blog {
    index index.php;
    rewrite ^/blog/(.*)+$ /blog/index.php?$1; # it finally works
    # return 200 $request_uri; # it is for inspect what $request_uri is
    # try_files $uri $uri/ /blog/index.php$request_uri$is_args$args; # it gets 500 server error
}
```

Please point out if current setting has any problems. thank you!

Comment: I get "This webpage has a redirect loop".

Comment: @Ryan remove any other configurations from this server { } block, as it will still read them after this - causing infinite loops. I got around it by setting location /blog { } for blog, and location / { } for main index.

Comment: This didn't pass variables properly for me. `location /blog/ {
try_files $uri $uri/ /blog/index.php?$args;
}` ended up working

Comment: Your code works well except /wp-admin/ redirect loop.

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest the following, to catch any permalinks under subfolder /blog

```
location /blog {
    index index.php;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /blog/index.php?$args;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, I changed my answer to try to imitate the same behaviour you are using in your rewrite.

```
location ~ /blog(.*) {
    index index.php;
    try_files $uri /blog/index.php?$1&$args;
}
```

Comment: Thank your for your reply. But I follow your instructions, it becomes `HTTP 500`.

Comment: @Cauliturtle try this differnet answer.

Comment: Then when I try to visit /blog/post-name, Chrome tries to download the page as a file.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
location /api {
    # example: http://demo.com/api/channels/dmzb
    root   /data/webserver/demo.com/api/web;
    rewrite ^/api/(.*) /$1 break;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /api/index.php?$args;

    location ~ ^/api/index\.php {
        fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi.conf;

        # fix request_uri
        set $changed_request_uri $request_uri;
        if ($changed_request_uri ~ ^/api(.*)) {
            set $changed_request_uri $1;
        }
        fastcgi_param REQUEST_URI $changed_request_uri;

        # fix script_filename
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(?:\/api\/)(.+\.php)(.*);
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Think for php, rewrite is no needed with something like this:

```
location /app/ {
  include fastcgi_params;
  fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME /path/to/your/app/index.php;
  fastcgi_pass php;
}
```

With following fastcgi pass

```
upstream php {
    server unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A universal solution for pretty URLs in root and one subfolder level:

```
set $virtualdir "";
set $realdir "";

if ($request_uri ~ ^/([^/]*)/.*$ ) {
        set $virtualdir /$1;
}

if (-d "$document_root$virtualdir") {
        set $realdir "${virtualdir}";
}

location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ $realdir/index.php?$args;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that with permalink enabled, I needed a combination of both sets of answers given here, otherwise

1. With only the rewrite, none of the static files got served
2. With only the try files, the permalinks did not work

This is working on my set up

```
location /blog/ {
      rewrite ^/blog/(blog/(tag|category|20??)/.*)+$ /blog/index.php?$1;
      try_files $uri $uri/ /blog/index.php?$args =404;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ip url:    123.123.123/xxxxxxxxxx/

```
location /xxxxxxxxxx/ {
   try_files $uri $uri/ /xxxxxxxxxx/index.php?$query_string;
}

# Rewrite multisite '.../wp-.*' and '.../*.php'.
if (!-e $request_filename) {
    rewrite ^(/xxxxxxxxxx/.*)+(/wp-.*) /xxxxxxxxxx/$2 last;
    rewrite ^(/xxxxxxxxxx/.*)+.*(/wp-admin/.*\.php)$ /xxxxxxxxxx/$2 last;
    rewrite ^(/xxxxxxxxxx/.*)+(/.*\.php)$ /xxxxxxxxxx/$2 last;

}
```